# Writing a script in Java?

Tags: java, linux, scripting

I am working with telecom company. I am familiar with Java programming language. But now I have a task to write a script, with Linux operating systems. I have to write a script for fetching data from other computer and check some conditions. How can I do that using Java?

Comment: You want to write a script. And you want to use Java? But java is no scripting language... Do you want to *call* a java applicaiton from your script??

Comment: What script  - Javascript, shell script, Perl script, ... ?

Comment: What exactly would you qualify as a "script" and how is it different from writing any other program? There are tons of definitions on depending on which one you subscribe to, it may be impossible or trivial to write a script in Java.

Comment: Why close? He knows java and wants to use it for scripting. I think the answer would be to use the beanshell (www.beanshell.org) as interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to write a "script" and it needs to run on the Java runtime, I would recommend using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). By "script" I mean,

> A scripting language, script language
>   or extension language is a programming
>   language that allows control of one or
>   more software applications.

If you just have to use straight Java, then you need to just write a command line program.
I recommend using [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) ( Java Simple Argument Parser ) for [parsing the command line arguments](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/10/command-line-argument-parsing-for-groovy/), you are going to need it. And either way you go you will need to bundle this Java code as an application.
  Here is a post on [how to build an executable .jar file](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/11/how-to-bundle-command-line-programs-into-a-single-executable-jar-file/), so you can deploy your application anywhere without having to set up a bunch of CLASSPATH voodoo.

Answer (score 3):

Java is not a scripting language by any definition.

Why not use a better tool for the job such as a shell script or even a simple interpreted language such as Perl, Python or Ruby?

Just to give you some incentive, here are the snippets for opening and reading a file in Python as opposed to Java.

Python:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

Java:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), encoding);
try {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
  }
}
finally {
  scanner.close();
}
```

Alternatively, if you must write in any language on top of the JVM, use Jython (Python for the JVM) or a language such as Groovy.

Comment: Or Groovy or JPython, if he wants to stay inside the Java infrastructure.

Comment: +1 to counteract -1 since, although it doesn't necessarily answer the question, I think this is a good clarification and belongs with this question